# Error: The operation is insecure. image not convert in canvas base64 in amazon server url

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, html5-canvas, base64

Error: The operation is insecure.
image not convert in base64 in Amazon server URL.
but other server are converted in base64.
pleas help me.

Comment: Enable [cross-origin resource sharing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

Comment: @markE can you explain me why sometimes experienced users prefer to leave a commment than a short answer? is there any reason i do not see?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi. Some questions can be answered by simply linking the questioner to a resource they didn't know they needed. But "link-only" answers are not quality Stackoverflow answers because of link-rot and because the true answer exists outside SO. This question contains too few details to help beyond getting them started with a link. It is probably a duplicate but there are to few details to even be sure of that. So I've also voted to close this question for lack of details. Helping with a comment (not answer) makes it easier to close the question if necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do I set CORS settings to and where so that my canvas doesn't get tainted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002392/what-do-i-set-cors-settings-to-and-where-so-that-my-canvas-doesnt-get-tainted)

Comment: @markE A better quality duplicate came after this question :)

Answer (score 0):

as @markE showed in his comment:

Follow Amazon dev guide and check how to enable cross origins requests on your resources.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: This document shows how to configure the bucket for xhr cross-origin requests, it's even simpler for just media, which won't have a preflight request : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002392/what-do-i-set-cors-settings-to-and-where-so-that-my-canvas-doesnt-get-tainted/35014782#35014782