# What do I set CORS settings to and where so that my canvas doesn't get tainted?

Tags: canvas, amazon-s3, html5-canvas, cors

I have a big canvas with icons and pictures that all come from my S3 bucket. When I'm trying to upload it (which runs `toDataUrl`) Chrome complains that

> Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases
>   may not be exported.

I've encountered this error before, but my solution that time was to host all the images locally. This is not possible this time, however, so I will need to tackle this issue head on.

Googling this issue brings up a lot of stuff about CORS, which I don't understand.

I've tried the following settings in my S3 bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>Anonymous</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This, however, does not work.

My intuition tells me I have to change something in the server as well, otherwise what is the purpose of this security requirement?

So what do I change, and *where*, so that my canvas won't be tainted anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CORS configuration should be good, the minimal needed being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

What you need however, is to set your `<img>`'s [`crossOrigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin) to `"anonymous"`.

Also, check that the image on s3 has been made Public (there should be a grantee `Everyone` set to `Open/Download`), and that you use the link available in the `Properties` tab of your image file (something like <sub>[image]</sub>`https://s3.yourRegion.amazonaws.com/userName/Folder/file.png`).

And finally, you have to clear the browser's cache after you changed your bucket's CORS setting, otherwise the browser won't make a new request to the server and it will use the unsafe version it has cached.

Comment: Oh. I have a lot of these: `var background = document.getElementById('background')` with various variable names. What's the syntax to set crossorigin for those?

Comment: @Yeats you have to set the `crossOrigin` attribute of the `<img>` tag, or the `.crossOrigin` property of its DOM object **before** loading the image, otherwise, the browser won't make the request to get an origin-safe resource, and the image will taint the canvas.

Comment: "Image from origin 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Are you sure you got the correct link and that the image has been made Public?

Comment: Very sure. I've been working with those pictures for a long time.

Comment: Wow, I just stumbled over the solution. I had to move the bucket name FIRST, like a sudomain. So the format `s3.yourRegion.etc/bucketname/image.png"` is wrong, it needs to be `bucketname.s3.yourRegion.etc/image.png`

Comment: I'm not sure how you did configure your s3, but on mine, the url format in my answer does work.

Comment: Haven't configured it beyond the CORS settings pasted here. The docs say "with CORS, you can configure your bucket to explicitly enable cross-origin requests from website.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com."

Comment: Have you got a link? Maybe this is region dependent (I'm on pacific one and it's quite late now btw)

Comment: To the docs? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#example-scenarios-cors

Comment: Okay, it worked now with literally no changes beyond commenting stuff out and then bringing it back in again. Could the first error have been a cache problem?

Comment: @Yeats, that's exactly what I thought when my head reached the pillow yesterday :-) Yes you have to clear the browser's cache after you changed your bucket's CORS setting, otherwise the browser won't make a new request to the server and it will use the unsafe version it has cached. I will edit the answer to include that too, you may not be the only one running in this issue ;-)

Comment: Also, the url in the link you provided is for "javascript requests" (i.e `XMLHttpRequest` in modern browsers), which need to do a pre-flight request for cross-origin requests. There is no such pre-flight request done for cross-origin media such as images. So the url format I posted is the good one for images.